# Should I delete my answer containing a result and a hint, if a complete answer is posted later?

Tags: discussion, answers, deletion

I'm asking about [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/393013/19661). I posted my answer a while ago, containing only the final result and a hint about where to search for a proof. I intended that I would post the full proof later, but actually never got enough time and enthusiasm to do that.

Now, [another answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/584901/19661) is posted and accepted, containing a correct full proof leading to the same result. The approach shown in the answer is basically the same that I used when I derived the result, so it would not make much sense now for me to post a duplicate solution.

Now my answer looks kinda useless and redundant. What the best thing I can do with it now? Should I delete it, or leave as is, or anything else?

Comment: I wouldn't worry about it. I do think that you can now skip the part about completing your hint to a full answer :-)

Comment: I answered the question since it had been over 6 months since your answer.  The approach I took did not use Jonquière's formula or Hurwitz's formula, so from your suggestions, I thought that I would be avoiding your approach. Since your answer was posted first, I see no reason to delete it; rather consider my answer support for yours.

Comment: Should Fermat's last theorem be called Fermat-Wiles theorem or Wiles' theorem?

Comment: @julien Maybe the Wiles-Taylor theorem....